# Cantelli Inequality Variant

Tags: probability-inequalities

In the JASA (1968, vol. 63, no. 324, pp. 1522-1525) article "How Deviant Can You Be?" Paul Samuelson notes two versions of Chebyshev's inequality:

$$P \left( \lvert  {X-\mu} \rvert \geq k \sigma \right) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$

and

$$P \left( \lvert  {X-\mu} \rvert \gt k \sigma \right) \lt \frac{1}{k^2}$$

In a footnote, he states "Neither form of Chebyshev's inequality is stronger than the other; neither logically implies the other directly; both are true."

I'm wondering if the situation is similar for the one-sided versions (Cantelli's inequality). Online I have only seen this (Wikipedia, for example):

$$  P \left(  X \geq \mu +k \sigma \right) \leq \frac{1}{k^2+1}$$

So, is it true for any real random variable $X$ with finite mean and variance that

$$  P \left(  X \gt \mu +k \sigma \right) \lt \frac{1}{k^2+1} \ ? $$

It seems to me that this is the case. For example, a specific instance is shown here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800931/a-version-of-one-sided-chebyshevs-inequality

So is it true in the general case?